# Building Apache Spark using SBT: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-1.4

I'm trying to install Spark on my local machine. I have been following [this](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/) guide. I have installed `JDK-7` (also have `JDK-8`) and `Scala 2.11.7`. A problem occurs when I try to use `sbt` to build `Spark 1.4.1`. I get the following exception.

```
NOTE: The sbt/sbt script has been relocated to build/sbt.
      Please update references to point to the new location.

      Invoking 'build/sbt assembly' now ...

Attempting to fetch sbt
Launching sbt from build/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile build/sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar
```

I have searched for a solution to this problem. I have found a nice guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597283/2771315 which uses a pre-built version. Other than using the pre-built version, is there a way to install `Spark` using `sbt`? Further, is there a reason as to why the `Invalid or corrupt jarfile` error occurs?

Comment: I suggest trying to use Scala 2.10 instead.  2.11 requires doing some additional processing on the build, but the last time I used 2.11 on trunk,  I also had to manually change some source files too. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211

Comment: Whether you use Scala 2.11 or 2.10, Spark's Maven build is better maintained than the SBT build, so follow the instructions here for building: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I met the same problem. I have fixed it now.

This probably because sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar has a unsuccessful download, although you can see the file is exist, but it's not correct file. The file is **about 1.2MB** in size. If less than that, you can get into the build/ , use "vim sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar" or other tools to **open sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar** file.

If the file have the content like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It implys that sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar is not downloaded.
Then open **sbt-launch-lib.bash** in the same directory,check the line 41 and 42, it gives two urls. Open it to check if they work well.

If url1 doesn't work，download the **sbt-launch.jar** manually(you can use url2, it may works,or you can download from sbt official website), put it in the same directory, **rename it to sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar**, then you shoud comment lines in relation to the downloading(may be between line 47 and 68)， avoid the script download it again. Like this:

```
acquire_sbt_jar () {
  SBT_VERSION=`awk -F "=" '/sbt\.version/ {print $2}'    ./project/build.properties`
  URL1=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/${SBT_VERSION}/sbt-launch.jar
  URL2=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/${SBT_VERSION}/sbt-launch.jar
  JAR=build/sbt-launch-${SBT_VERSION}.jar

  sbt_jar=$JAR

 # if [[ ! -f "$sbt_jar" ]]; then
 #   # Download sbt launch jar if it hasn't been downloaded yet
 #   if [ ! -f "${JAR}" ]; then
 #   # Download
 #   printf "Attempting to fetch sbt\n"
 #   JAR_DL="${JAR}.part"
 #   if [ $(command -v curl) ]; then
 #     (curl --silent ${URL1} > "${JAR_DL}" || curl --silent ${URL2} > "${JAR_DL}") && mv "${JAR_DL}" "${JAR}"
 #   elif [ $(command -v wget) ]; then
 #     (wget --quiet ${URL1} -O "${JAR_DL}" || wget --quiet ${URL2} -O "${JAR_DL}") && mv "${JAR_DL}" "${JAR}"
 #   else
 #     printf "You do not have curl or wget installed, please install sbt manually from http://www.scala-sbt.org/\n"
 #     exit -1
 #   fi
 #   fi
 #   if [ ! -f "${JAR}" ]; then
 #   # We failed to download
 #   printf "Our attempt to download sbt locally to ${JAR} failed. Please install sbt manually from http://www.scala-sbt.org/\n"
 #   exit -1
 #   fi
 #   printf "Launching sbt from ${JAR}\n"
 # fi
 }
```

Then use "build/sbt assembly" to build the spark again.

Hope you will succeed.

If I didn't express clearly, the following links may be helpful.

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg34358.html

[Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.5.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594937/error-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile-sbt-sbt-launch-0-13-5-jar/31597283#31597283)  the answer by prabeesh

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/fllCh8n-0d4

Comment: This is a very Spark-like thing to need to do.

Comment: do yu have any answer so far? I met exactly the same problem as you did!

Answer (score 0):

Download the sbt-launch.jar file manually (you can use url2, it may work, or you can download from the sbt official website), put it in the same directory, rename it to sbt-launch-0.13.7.jar, then run the sbt/sbt assembly command.